# Azure data factory: How to get first row from a stream in data flow transformation

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I get the latest row from a stream in data flow transformation. Below is the sql equivalent query. I checked filter mapping transformation but I did find any relevant function in visual expression builder. I amnew to data factory and I am currently exploring the data flow canvas.

**SQL: Select Top 1 * from XYZ table order by timestamp desc;**

Answer (score 0):

In Source transformation, under source options, you can select the Input as Query and write the SQL query to get the latest record.

[image]